# Apache taking ownership of file and folder

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, permissions, python, django

I have django site running on Ubuntu with apache2 configured with mod_wsgi. The `media` (folder where user uploaded files go) is owned by ubuntu user (with sudo access) and the group of `media` folder is `www-data`. When new folder or files are created by apache in media folder some external Python process (e.g. `subprocess.popen`) is not able to write in that folder as that particular folder is owned by `www-data`. What is the solution of this problem?

What I have done so far (`django` is the system user):

```
sudo chown django:django -R mysite/media/
sudo chgrp -R www-data mysite/media/
sudo chmod -R g+w mysite/media/
```

`ls -la` result of `media` folder (media folder contains some other folders named with integers):

```
drwxr-sr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Jun  8 02:20 11
drwxrwsr-x  6 django   www-data 4096 Jun  7 18:15 10
drwxrwsr-x  5 django   www-data 4096 Jun  7 18:13 9
drwxrwsr-x  5 django   www-data 4096 Jun  7 18:11 8
```

As you can see the newly created folder `11` is owned by `www-data` not by `django` user.

What else i have tried:

- i have tried to add user `django` to `www-data` group but nothing helps

Please help!

**Update**

Unfortunately `Daniel` solution also does not work for me (still getting `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`). Here are result of command `getfacl mysite/site_media/`:

**Before**

```
# file: mysite/site_media/
# owner: django
# group: www-data
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
```

**After** (`sudo setfacl -d -R -m g:www-data:rwx mysite/site_media/`)

```
# file: mysite/site_media/
# owner: django
# group: www-data
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:www-data:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use file access control lists, in this case `setfacl` to set default file permission to allow write operation for the group. If you have added django to the www-data group, then with the following command, the django user will have write permission on any files owned by www-data user.

```
    setfacl -d -R -m g:www-data:rwx mysite/media/
```

Note: you will need to install the `acl` package using `apt-get install acl` if it is not installed. Make sure also ACL is enabled for your partition - [this link might help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs).

Comment: unfortunately your solution does not work either. Check the results i have updated my question.

Comment: Any hints please? I am stuck :(

Comment: Thanks daniel your answers helps me somewhat. But the problem was somewhere else. See my answer. Anyhow offering you bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was of shared memory. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009278/python-multiprocessing-permission-denied) answer helped it to fix it.

Adding `none /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0` in `/etc/fstab` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your directory output, at permissions of the directory `11` to be precise, I've found that apache created it with group readable but not group writable permissions. Since you might want all users in group `www-data` to have write permissions for these files/directories, you need to tell apache to create files/dirs with group write permissions that can be acomplished by setting `umask` option to [WSGIDaemonProcess](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess). Since documentation says:

> Typically the inherited umask would be `0022`

you'll always get no group writable permissions set. All you need in this case is just set umask value to `0002` and restart apache. You may solve this problem by just running WSGIDaemon as user `django` by specifying relevant user name.

Answer (score 0):

I don;t fully understand your description of the problem, but think the problem is he setgid bit i.e. the 's' in:

```
drwxr-sr-x
```

Have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories for a description written better than I can give it. The `chmod` man page too. Basically look for info in setgud. It behaves differently on directories than it does on files.

Try `chmod g-s` on the media dir and then create a sub dir in media and see if that has stopped it from inheriting the wrong perms.
If it has you just need to remvoe the setgid bit from all the other sub dirs.

For that `find` is your friend (it can search on owners groups and perms)

Comment: Thanks jason. But the problem is solved now i have answered my own question. Initially it was not even letting me create directories so `Daniel` answer helps me to do that. Then the python subprocess was not able to open file for writing, it turns out to be shared memory issue.

Comment: Glad you have it going.